# Java Regex String pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

I need to find the pattern matching for the below string:

```
HI {{contact::first_name=testok}} and Tag value {{contact::last_name=okie}}
```

So the pattern matcher should return below two strings as the result:

```
{{contact::first_name=testok}}
{{contact::last_name=okie}}
```

I have written regex pattern as this, since after `=` it can contain any characters so i added `.*`

```
\{\{(contact|custom)::[_a-zA-Z0-9]+=?.*\}\}
```

but the above regex pattern is returning like this

```
{{contact::first_name=testok}} and Tag value {{contact::last_name=okie}}
```

Any solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this pattern `(\{\{.*?\}\})`

here [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ecpo5R/9)

Answer (score 0):

You can utterly simplify your pattern to get whatever's in between double curly brackets (brackets included), by specifying the brackets alongside a reluctant quantifier (will grab as much as possible until the first occurrence of the closing brackets).

```
String input = "HI {{contact::first_name=testok}} and Tag value {{contact::last_name=okie}}";
//                           | escaped curly bracket * 2
//                           |     | reluctant quantifier for any character 1+ occurrence
//                           |     |  | closing curlies
//                           |     |  | 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{.+?\\}\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: {{contact::first_name=testok}}
Found: {{contact::last_name=okie}}
```

Comment: your solution is not working when string is something like `{{}}` because use add `+` so `}` take as a character and output is wrong

Comment: Yes, I specifically specify that in the comments (see "1+ occurrence" part). A zero-ĺength input is possible with the `*` pattern, but for structured text it might not be a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("HI {{contact::first_name=testok}} and Tag value {{contact::last_name=okie}}");

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Explanation of the regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/7zGGm4/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursive pattern: `{{.*?(\1)*.*?}}`

Explanation:

`.*?` - capture zero or more occurences of any character (non-greedy)

`(\1)*` - match again whole pattern (zero or more times)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h4BjGe/1)